# PivotTable keep giving me every adress for every city

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am currenty learning pivot table in excel. I am trying get a table that has "Cities" in the first column and "adresses" in the second column in tabular form. The cities comes out nice but the adresses are not correct. All the adresses is printed out for every city, even though they dont belong to that city.

Hoe should I fix this?

It should be looking like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you have more than 1 row with the same City and Address? If not, it doesn't make sense to include Address in the pivot table rows.

Pivot tables are for aggregating data, so at least one of your key columns need to be left out of the rows box.

Comment: Yes, I have - see attached picture above.

Comment: I have seen the type of behavior described with pivot tables produced from a data model. Is that the case here? If so, is there a table of unique cities and a table of unique addresses?